# Windows 10 Git-bash: Which script sets ORIGINAL_PATH during git-bash start up

Tags: mingw, git-bash

When I launch Windows `git-bash` ver. 2.21.0, `/etc/profile` assigns `%PATH%` to `$ORIGINAL_PATH` and adds a few `mingw` paths which eventually become the `$PATH` in the `bash` shell.

However, inside `/etc/profile`, `$ORIGINAL_PATH` is not the same as `%PATH%`. It is already configured with extra `/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/u/Users/foo_user/bin:` added to `%PATH%`. Which file/script set `$ORIGINAL_PATH` before /etc/profile? Thanks

Comment: [Zsh/Bash startup files loading order (.bashrc, .zshrc etc.) | The Lumber Room](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/)

Comment: i checked `/etc/bash.bashrc` and found nothing that sets `PATH` nor `ORIGINAL_PATH`

Comment: Check **all** of the startup files ...

Comment: I did. I checked the files in `c:\program files\Git\`, and `/etc` in `git-bash.exe` console. I am guessing the additional paths added to `$PATH` are hardwired in `git-bash.exe`

Comment: A partial answer to this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/61959957/9223868 - `/u/Users/foo_user/bin` is being added by `/etc/profile.d/env.sh`. Though I don't know which file invokes `env.sh` or what's adding the other two.

Answer (score 0):

[cat /etc/profile](https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/blob/master/filesystem/profile)

There are `ORIGINAL_PATH`, `ORIGINAL_TMP`, `ORIGINAL_TEMP`